# How configure for a (Optional) OneToOne Composite Primary Key?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate and have two tables, STUDENTS and DORM_ROOMS, that are related with a composite key:

```
STUDENTS table:
CAMPUS(String)      Part of Composite Key
STUDENT_ID (int)    Part of Composite Key
NAME (String)
...

DORM_ROOMS table:
CAMPUS(String)      Part of Composite Key
STUDENT_ID (int)    Part of Composite Key
ROOM_NUMBER(int)
...
```

The relationship is one to one because a student can be associated with exactly one dorm room and and a dorm room is associated with one student (wow - a private room!).  However, not all students have a dorm room.

My initial code (stripped down) looks like:

```
FOR STUDENTS:
@Embeddable
public class StudentsPK implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "CAMPUS")
private String Campus;
@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
private String StudentID;
...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Students implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
private StudentsPK studentsPK;
...
}


FOR DORM_ROOMS:
@Embeddable
public class DormRoomsPK implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "CAMPUS")
private String Campus;
@Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
private String StudentID;
...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "DORM_ROOMS")
public class DormRooms implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
private DormRoomsPK dormRoomsPK;
...
}
```

Assume that the database schema is already defined and created.  In particular, CAMPUS+STUDENT_ID is a PK for STUDENTS and CAMPUS+STUDENT_ID is a FK for DORM_ROOMS that serves as the PK in that table.  At this point I can successfully insert a row into STUDENTS and a row into DORM_ROOMS.  I can also retrieve any student from STUDENTS even if the student does not have a dorm room.  However, I have not yet "informed" Hibernate about the relationship between the two tables. That is where I am confused.

I tried to "relate" the two tables by using a "JOIN" annotation but I discovered that this causes any attempt to fetch a student that has no dorm room to return an empty result set.  I suppose that makes since if "JOIN" states that the tables are to always be viewed as joined then joining a student having no dorm room with no matching rows in the DORM_ROOMS table would result in an empty result set.

Since using a "JOIN" annotation doesn't work, how do I modify my code to describe the relationship between the two tables but still allow me to fetch students that have no matching dorm rooms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the [@OneToOne annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html), which also has the ability to specify if the relationship is [optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#optional()). There are some examples described in the [JBoss JPA 2.1 docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/), here is one of them.

```
Example 3: One-to-one association from an embeddable class to another entity.

@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id int id;
  @Embedded LocationDetails location;
  ...
}

@Embeddable
public class LocationDetails {
  int officeNumber;
  @OneToOne ParkingSpot parkingSpot;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class ParkingSpot {
  @Id int id;
  String garage;
  @OneToOne(mappedBy="location.parkingSpot") Employee assignedTo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!  I discovered that in a @OneToOne relationship with a composite key, using a separate FK class to manage the composite key in both entities causes the error.  The problem is shown in my original posting where I define and use StudentsPK and DormRoomsPK!  Once I changed to use a single "PK" class instead of these two my problem was eliminated.  (This doesn't appear to be a well documented requirement!)